# How to find closest approximation to a matrix multiplied by a scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, approximation, matrix-equations

I have a simple problem:

`a x M` is close to `N`

How to find the scalar `a` so that the two matrices, `M and N` are close to each other?

The metric is L2 norm. Any pointers to other norms would be helpful as well, in general if the approximation would still be useful and easily approximated.

Comment: Do you have a metric?

Comment: @JorgeFernández-Hidalgo The matrices M and N should minimize the euclidean distance, i.e. L2 norm

Answer (score 1):

we want to minimize $\sum\limits_{i,j} (aM_{ij} - N_{ij})^2 = \ a^2(\sum\limits_{i,j} M_{ij})- 2a\sum\limits_{i,j}M_{i,j}N_{i,j} + \sum\limits_{i,j} N_{ij}$.

So this is just an expression of the form $a^2c_2 + ac_1 + c_0$ which clearly occurs when $a = - \frac{c_1}{2c_2}$

Comment: Is the term for c1 correct? do all elements of M need to multiplied with the diagonal elements of N?